# Customize error message depends on condition in JSR 303

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

I have the following code:

```
    ....
    @AssertTrue(message = "I want to customize this message")
    public boolean isValidPrice() {
        if (...) {
            return false; // error message 1
        }
        if (...) {
            return false; // error message 2
        }
         if (...) {
            return false; // error message 3
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I need to return different error messages depends on condition

Does `JSR 303` allow this?

P.S.

`error message 2` should not be shown if `error message 1` have already shown

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. The constraint validator just knows that `false` is returned. There is no way to know why `false` is returned. Also, the implementation of `isValidPrice` has no knowledge of the `@AssertTrue` constraints.